# Undefined match url in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a web layout like

```
***************************************************
* Category  *              Main Area              *
*           *                                     *
* Link 1    *                                     *
* Link 2    *                                     *
* Link 3    *                                     *
```

When I click **Link 1** for example, it will give me the following URL:

`http://localhost:3000/undefined/Link1`

And worst when I click **Link 2** after that, it will give me this:

`http://localhost:3000/undefined/undefined/Link2`

I'm looking at Ryan Florence's [tutorial](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) on `React Router 4` which is fairly easy to follow. But when I try to implement it in my own website which I am planning to do, it give me undefined link as mentioned earlier. I am new to React and React Router as well and I have tried to solve it myself so far but can't.

Here is my **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MainLayout from './MainLayout';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../App.css';

class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="row">
      <Router>
        <MainLayout>
        </MainLayout>
      </Router>
    </div>
   );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My **MainLayout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import SideBar from './SideBar';
import Main from './Main';

const MainLayout=()=> {
 return(
    <div>
        <SideBar />
        <Main />
    </div>
   )
 }

export default MainLayout;
```

My **SideBar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../readable-logo.png';
import { Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReadableList from './ReadableList';

const SideBar = (match) => {
 return(
    <div className="col s3 z-depth-1 App-col-all">
        <img className="responsive-img z-depth-1" src={logo} alt="logo here"/>
        <div className="row">
            <h5 className="center">Categories</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/link1`}>Link 1</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/link2`}>Link 2</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/link3`}>Link 3</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <Route path={`${match.url}/:categoryId`} component={ReadableList}/>   
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}

export default SideBar;
```

And finally my **Main.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <div className="App-col-all">
            <div className="col s9">
                <p>Main</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: That's because you aren't using any `Route`s with `SideBar`.

Comment: I have a `Route` in my `SideBar.js`, should I add one also at `App.js`?

Comment: Yeah. You'd need to somehow wrap `Sidebar` in a `Route` or pass `match` down.

Comment: I tried to do this in my **App.js** `<Route path="/" component={MainLayout}/>` but it does not work. Tried also to do it on **MainLayout** the following, `<Route path="/" component={SideBar}/>` but still will not work.

Comment: You get that error because `match.url` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReadableList.js

```
// ReadableList.js
import React from 'react';

const ReadableList = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {match.params.categoryId}
    </div>
  )
};

export default ReadableList;
```

Main.js

```
// Main.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReadableList from './ReadableList';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App-col-all">
        <div className="col s9">
          <Route path="/" exact={true} render={() => (
            <p>Main</p>
          )} />
          <Route path="/g/:categoryId" component={ReadableList} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

SideBar.js

```
// SideBar.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="col s3 z-depth-1 App-col-all">
      <img className="responsive-img z-depth-1" src="{logo}" alt="logo here" />
      <div className="row">
        <h5 className="center">Categories</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/g/link1">Link 1</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/g/link2">Link 2</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/g/link3">Link 3</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default SideBar;
```

Check out my solution, you can modify it according to your needs:

[image: Edit 1ojz20750j]

Comment: Thanks a lot John, this could be a good starter for me. But in your example it did not show dynamic routing using `params` which what I want to do.

Comment: I used `match.params` in the ReadableList component, t'was passed in as a prop. This might not be visible in the current state of the app on CodeSandbox as I got carried away and implemented the app fully using some APIs.

Comment: Used `params` in the `Main.js` file

Comment: I think yours is right. I now realize my (rookie) mistake that I should have not used the `{match.url}` not until a link on a sub-link is clicked. It now works by the way, as I want it to be. Thanks and GOD bless.

Comment: @JohnKennedy It will not work when you refresh the page. I have followed the same thing in my project. Here is the [https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Did you use my code sample on codesandbox?

Comment: Yes I am following your tutorial. Kindly user the Url which i have provided. I am able to do the same thing as mentioned above in reference link. But i am getting my Home page url in `${match.url}` this variable everytime. If you found something to get current url than update here.

Comment: @JohnKennedy  Also use this line in you sidebar export `export default withRotuer(SideBar);` than you will to get `${match.url}`. But currently i am getting only home page url not my parent route url. Let me know if you get some solution on this.

Comment: There's no need for that. My example was intended. If you're concerned about the refresh, you could implement redux or the like to fire an action when the component loads then using `withRouter` you can access the url and fetch data for that user.
My example was meant to be simple, no complex logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../readable-logo.png';
import { Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReadableList from './ReadableList';
import {withRouter} from 'react-rotuer'

const SideBar = ({match}) => {
 return(
    <div className="col s3 z-depth-1 App-col-all">
        <img className="responsive-img z-depth-1" src={logo} alt="logo here"/>
        <div className="row">
            <h5 className="center">Categories</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/link1`}>Link 1</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/link2`}>Link 2</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to={`${match.url}/link3`}>Link 3</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <Route path={`${match.url}/:categoryId`} component={ReadableList}/>   
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}

export default withRotuer(SideBar);
```

Comment: I am using `Router 4` and it allows dynamic routing. Also in its documentation it has an example on routing from [sidebar](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar).

Comment: You are right... but what's the point of the sidebar if you are not going to change the main content after clicking on the links..

Comment: That's what I want to do, when you click on the sidebar link you change the content of the main page and the side bar link values are `param` that I could use to filter out my database.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try but still `undefined`.

Comment: I found it.. change `export default SideBar` to `export defatult withRouter(SideBar)` and import withRouter like that 
`import { withRouter } from 'react-router'` and replace this line `const SideBar = (match) => {` by this `const SideBar = ({match}) => {`

Answer (score 0):

`match` isn't the only prop being passed to the `SideBar` component. You will either need to use `props.match.url` or destructure the props like so

```
const SideBar = ({match}) => {
   //...
}
```

And if your component isn't receiving the `react-router` props correctly for some reason, you can try to wrap your component in the `withRouter()` HOC.

Comment: I already tried this before, but it's very interesting that when I use `{match}` as parameter for my **SideBar** it gave me the `undefined url property error` for `match.url`.

Comment: Did you try the second part of my suggestion? [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)